# Ms-Access Query is getting deleted automatically. What can be the reason?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-office

Some of the queries I have written inside MS-Access are getting deleted automatically. And while I run the queries through code, I get this error:

> Query should have one destination field

What can be the possible reason?

**Explanation**: I created a query in MS-access. Ran it from the code. Closed the database. Started it again, and now for that particular query, it is showing `'SELECT ;'` only.

Strange. I am in panic mode now

**BPray Adding:**
I am experiencing the same thing in a database.  It is very strange and I am not sure what is happening or why.  The database is over 5 years old and this just started happening recently.

The database is seemingly "deleting" the SQL from queries so the query itself is "blank".  The query isn't returning blank results, if you open the query design or SQL, there is literally nothing there (other than the 'SELECT;' mentioned above).

This has happened in this database a few times now and it isn't the same query that gets blown away.  There also doesn't seem to be a specific action that initiates the problem.

I fear I will need to rebuild this database but wanted to see if anyone else had experienced this and knows of a resolution.

We are using a 32bit version of Access and are on Office 365.  I have run a Compact & Repair.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain "are getting deleted automatically"?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide the relevant SQL for your Query/Queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your query actually has any fields in the query design grid. When you open the query in design view, you will most likely notice it doesn't.

Comment: It did have fields initially. Does it make any difference if I am using * instead of writing all field names?

Comment: * should be fine, as it contains at least one field (provided your tables/queries are not all empty).

Answer (score 0):

Does the query stick around when you don't run the code (but still close and reopen the database)?

If so, I would suspect that something in your code is overwriting the query.